# OpenGL 2D Text in 3D Space [C++/GLM] Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c++, opengl, text, matrix

I was trying to display 2D text in using 3D coordinates.
I was following [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/) (Solution #1: The 2D way). I did everything as shown in this tutorial but something is probably wrong. Here is the code:

```
void Update()
{
    glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0,640.0/480.0,0.01,500.0);
    glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0),glm::vec3(0.0,0.0,-5.0),glm::vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0));
    glm::vec4 worldSpace(0.f,1.0,-5.f,1.0);
    glm::vec4 screenSpace = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * worldSpace;
    screenSpace /= screenSpace.w;

    ovlay.setPosition(screenSpace.x,screenSpace.y);
}
```

`projectionMatrix` is the perspective that I'm using.

`viewMatrix` is my camera position and direction.

`worldSpace` is the position in 3D that I want to use to calculate 2D coords.

`screenSpace` should give me the position in 2D space but I get some weird result:

`x = 0, y = 0.358518`

I think it should be something like `x = 320, y = 100`.

If someone knows what I did wrong I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, what this code calculates are *normalized device coordinates* of thet `worldSpace` point. The viewing volume is `[-1,1]` along all axis in this space, so `x=0` is exactly at the center and y=0.358518 is somewhere above the center.

If you want the window space position, you need to take the *viewport* into account. Assuming your viewport fillst the whole window of size `w` * `h` pixels, you can get the window position as:

```
wx = (x + 1.0f) * 0.5f * w;
wy = (y + 1.0f) * 0.5f * h;
```

Assuming the 640x480 resoluting suggested by your projection matrix, this would give (320, 326). I don't know why you'd expect y as 100. Note the GL uses the **bottom** left corner as origin. In typical window systems, origin is at the top, so y=326 in the GL would match y'=153 in that other convention.

Comment: Sorry i got used to top-left based coordinate system.